# Why is my form submitting in all browsers except IE7?

Tags: php, ajax, forms

I have a form that is submitting in every browser except for IE7.  In IE7, when clicking submit, the browser displays a blank white page and the address bar changes to the address for my PHP file which processes and submits the form.

Here is the form: http://www.hancockclaims.com/schedule-a-claimassist/

You can leave the form blank in IE7 and just click submit and you will see it loads a blank white page.  In other browers, when the form is blank it points out the required fields and when the form is filled in, it submits.

Here is the contents of my "schedule_claim.php" file which processes the form:

http://pastebin.com/R3NbXfn5

I cannot for the life of me, figure out why IE7 is not working.  I have spent hours trying to find the issue, but I am just going around in circles now.

Would appreciate a solution with an explanation as to what the problem is and WHY it occurs in IE7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was being caused by an "," in functions.js - stupid IE7.

Answer (score 3):

In your [function.js](http://www.hancockclaims.com/wp-content/themes/hancock_wp/style/js/functions.js) file change:

```
$("#edit-submit").click(function() {
```

to

```
$("#edit-submit").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
```

IIRC `return false` doesn't work < IE8 so you're page is just submitting the data, not actually stopping the form from submitting. You could equally change

```
<input type="submit" class="form-submit" value="Submit" id="edit-submit" name="op">
```

to be a `button` instead of `input`.

Comment: I changed function.js per your tweak above, but the same behaviour still occurs.

Comment: have you checked the debug console in IE7 to make sure there are no JS errors? Also are you modifying the live server (I just wanted to check the change myself).

Comment: I pushed it to the live server now.  As far as I can see in the debug, there are no JS errors.